# Remove duplicates in JSON to CSV values using jq

Tags: syntax, duplicates, jq, export-to-csv

Here I'm trying to convert json to csv. Also, I'm trying to ignore duplicate values of 'color' attribute in same command. I have tried with below jq cmd and getting *bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('* error. Please help me to resolve this error.

```
 jq -r '["color","category","type"], ([].colors | 'unique_by(.color)' | [.color, .category, .type]) | @csv' test.json > test.csv
```

My JSON file:

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For what reason do you have the unique_by expression again under single quotes?

Comment: I removed those single quotes and tried again. Getting index number issue..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```sh
 jq -r '.colors | unique_by(.color)[] | [.color, .category, .type] | @csv'
```

```
"black","hue","primary"
"red","hue","primary"
"white","value",
"yellow","hue","primary"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RltBZOUFAj)

---

To add a default value (and make every line have the same amount of values), add `// "<default_value>"` when creating the final array. For instance, with `""` as default, it'd be:

```sh
 jq -r '.colors | unique_by(.color)[] | [.color//"", .category//"", .type//""] | @csv'
```

```
"black","hue","primary"
"red","hue","primary"
"white","value",""
"yellow","hue","primary"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8ubHc5cIoe)

Comment: Yes.. Thats my expected output. .But in my end, output is getting repeated for thrice.. How to remove them ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the "repeating" behaviour at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org) and post here the link obtained via "Share snippet"?

Comment: I posted this query as a different question. Please take a look..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898423/remove-duplicates-using-jq