# Remove duplicates using jq

Tags: syntax, duplicates, jq, export-to-csv

Here I'm trying to convert my json to csv with these conditions:- 1) ignore duplicate values of 'address' attribute using jq cmd. 2) Also, I have to ignore the duplicate json []. I have tried with below jq cmd, address attribute is getting ignored, *but duplicate json[] is not*. Please help on this.

My jq cmd:

```
jq -r '["Name","Address","Status"], (.| unique_by(.address)[] | [.name, .address, .status]) | @csv' sample.json > sample.csv
```

My JSON:

```
 [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ram",
        "address": "Kolkata",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Rahul",
        "address": "Kolkata",
        "status": "inactive"
       },
       {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kishore",
        "address": "Hyderabad",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Manu",
        "address": "Kerala",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Adam",
        "address": "Bangalore",
        "status": "inactive"
       }
    ]
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ram",
        "address": "Kolkata",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Rahul",
        "address": "Kolkata",
        "status": "inactive"
       },
       {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kishore",
        "address": "Hyderabad",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Manu",
        "address": "Kerala",
        "status": "active"
       },
       {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Adam",
        "address": "Bangalore",
        "status": "inactive"
       }
    ]
```

O/P:

```
"Name","Address","Status"
"Adam","Bangalore","inactive"
"Kishore","Hyderabad","active"
"Manu","Kerala","active"
"Ram","Kolkata","active"
"Name","Address","Status"
"Adam","Bangalore","inactive"
"Kishore","Hyderabad","active"
"Manu","Kerala","active"
"Ram","Kolkata","active"
```

Expected O/P:

```
"Name","Address","Status"
"Adam","Bangalore","inactive"
"Kishore","Hyderabad","active"
"Manu","Kerala","active"
"Ram","Kolkata","active"
```

Comment: You added the actual output. Can you add your expected output as well?

Comment: Is the issue that you have two arrays as input and they get deduplicated separately? Then try changing the first `.` to `inputs` yielding `… (inputs | unique_by( …`. ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jKdX-n9kHY))

Comment: Its working ! @pmf Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use slurp and flatten:

```
jq -rs '["Name","Address","Status"],
(flatten(1) | unique_by(.address)[] | [.name, .address, .status])
| @csv' sample.json > sample.csv
```

which will output:

```
"Name","Address","Status"
"Adam","Bangalore","inactive"
"Kishore","Hyderabad","active"
"Manu","Kerala","active"
"Ram","Kolkata","active"
```

Another solution was suggested by [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) in the comments: replace `.` with [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#inputs):

```
jq -r '["Name","Address","Status"], (inputs | unique_by(.address)[] | [.name, .address, .status]) | @csv' sample.json > sample.csv
```